# HTTP Server response - wrong content type?

Tags: c#, http, web

I'm making a server that should be able to store some images and then send/stream them to a client upon request. I've managed to get the server to respond with an image when I request it from a web browser, but when I send the very same HTTP request to the server from my client application, I'm not sure what exactly happens (it's supposed to become a tile map server at some point, but I'm starting out easy with just a single image here).

If it's of any help, here's an output from my web browser request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDbIE.png

And here the other one is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lspps.png

Fiddler is saying I'm returning Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 which in my head sounds horribly wrong when trying to return an image.

I've been digging around a little more and it seems the response is empty. It smells like my server isn't delivering the image properly to the client since I'm just using this piece of code to respond to the request:

```
if (p.http_url.Equals("/MapServer/tile/0/0/0"))
        {
            Stream fs = File.Open("../MapServer/tile/0,0,0.png", FileMode.Open);

            p.writeSuccess("image/jpeg");
            fs.CopyTo(p.outputStream.BaseStream);
            p.outputStream.BaseStream.Flush();
            fs.Close();
        }
```

I'm using StreamWriter for my stream. Is that the one giving me the content_type problems?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP servers map content type through other mechanisms. A Stream is too low-level to convey that kind of information; it doesn't distinguish between series of bytes for a text file or an image.

[The Content-type Saga](http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/www/content-type.html)

[Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html)

[Configuring MIME Types in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753281%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Try building your service to return something from the System.Net.Http namespace like [HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). These classes have the ability to provide more information about the type of document being sent.